# Postgresql SQL insert into with CTE is going on forever

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-12

I am struggling with an insert statement which used to work fine upto last week. It doesnt seem to complete and keeps on running forever without throwing an error. When its running I see locks being acquired on table INCLUDED_ENTITIES.

What I am trying to achieve is there are some exclusions defined in table AGREEMENT_PRODUCT_EXCLUSIONS at product_type. I am trying to find all those products from KNOWN_PRODUCTS for a given caseid and determining all those product_type which are not excluded. For example, known_products, exclusions and agreements are listed below. All known_products fall in category Der and will have caseid 10001 but PT1 is excluded. So the final outcome should be PT2 & PT3 be included for caseid 10001 with category Der.

```
product_type    date
PT1             2024-01-07
PT2             2024-01-07
PT3             2024-01-07

product_type   caseid        date
PT1            10001         2024-01-07

entity   branch cpty_entity  cpty_branch caseid product_category date
1        1      101          1           10001  Der              2024-01-07
1        1      101          2           10002  Der              2024-01-07
1        1      101          3           10003  Der              2024-01-07

  with BUSINESS_DATE as (
    select date(max(DATA_DATE)) as DATA_DATE from KNOWN_PRODUCTS
  )
  , CASEIDS as (
    select CASEID 
    from AGREEMENT_PRODUCT_EXCLUSIONS CAPE
    where date(DATA_DATE) = (select DATA_DATE from BUSINESS_DATE)
    group by CASEID 
  )
  , CASEID_PRODUCT as (
    select C.CASEID
          ,KP.PRODUCT_TYPE
          ,rank() over (order by C.CASEID, KP.PRODUCT_TYPE) as ID
          ,case
            when KP.PRODUCT_TYPE = 'R1' then 'Rep'
            when KP.PRODUCT_TYPE = 'S1' then 'Sec'
            else 'Der'
           end as PRODUCT_CATEGORY
    from CASEIDS C cross JOIN KNOWN_PRODUCTS KP
    where date(KP.DATA_DATE) = (select DATA_DATE from BUSINESS_DATE)
      and KP.PRODUCT_TYPE != '()'
  )
  , INCLUDED_PRODUCT_TYPE as (
    select AC.CASEID, AC.PRODUCT_TYPE, AC.PRODUCT_CATEGORY 
    from CASEID_PRODUCT AC
    left join AGREEMENT_PRODUCT_EXCLUSIONS E on AC.PRODUCT_TYPE = E.PRODUCT_TYPE
                                                 and AC.CASEID = E.CASEID
                                                 and date(E.DATA_DATE) = (select DATA_DATE from BUSINESS_DATE)
    where E.CASEID is null and E.PRODUCT_TYPE is null
  )
  , FINAL_DATA as (
    select CA.ENTITY
         , CA.BRANCH
         , CA.CPTY_ENTITY
         , CA.CPTY_BRANCH
         , IC.PRODUCT_TYPE
         , IC.PRODUCT_CATEGORY
    from INCLUDED_PRODUCT_TYPE IC
    join AGREEMENTS CA on CA.CASEID = IC.CASEID
                      and CA.PRODUCT_CATEGORY = IC.PRODUCT_CATEGORY
    where date(CA.DATA_DATE) = (select DATA_DATE from BUSINESS_DATE)
    group by CA.ENTITY
          , CA.BRANCH
          , CA.CPTY_ENTITY
          , CA.CPTY_BRANCH
          , IC.PRODUCT_TYPE
          , IC.PRODUCT_CATEGORY
  )
  insert into INCLUDED_ENTITIES(ENTITY, BRANCH, CPTY_ENTITY, CPTY_BRANCH, PRODUCT_TYPE, PRODUCT_CATEGORY)
  select ENTITY
       , BRANCH
       , CPTY_ENTITY
       , CPTY_BRANCH
       , PRODUCT_TYPE
       , PRODUCT_CATEGORY
  from FINAL_DATA;
```

Any idea what could be going on here? Thanks in advance.

AK

**Update 1**
Explain

```
1.   Insert on included_entities as included_entities       
2.   Aggregate      
3.   Seq Scan on known_products as known_products       
4.   Subquery Scan      
5.   Group      
6.   CTE Scan       
7.   CTE Scan       
8.   Sort       
9.   Nested Loop Anti Join
Join Filter: ((ac.product_type = (e.product_type)::text) AND (ac.caseid = e.caseid))
10.  Hash Inner Join
Hash Cond: ((ca.caseid = ac.caseid) AND (ca.product_category = ac.product_category))
11.  Seq Scan on agreements as ca
Filter: ((data_date)::date = $2)
12.  Hash       
13.  Subquery Scan      
14.  Nested Loop Inner Join     
15.  CTE Scan       
16.  Seq Scan on known_products as kp
Filter: ((product_type <> '()'::text) AND ((data_date)::date = $3))
17.  Group      
18.  CTE Scan       
19.  Sort       
20.  Seq Scan on agreement_product_exclusions as cape
Filter: ((data_date)::date = $4)
21.  Seq Scan on agreement_product_exclusions as e
Filter: ((data_date)::date = $1)
Total rows: 1 of 1
Query complete 00:00:00.144
Ln 38, Col 30
```

Comment: Can you post EXPLAIN results on http://explain.depesz.com?

Comment: Have you run the query by itself without the insert operation?

Comment: Added explain to question

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this by rewriting the query completely. There was an intermediate step where lots of duplicates where encountered which required a group by. Here is the updated query.

```
with BUSINESS_DATE as (
    select date(max(DATA_DATE)) as DATA_DATE from KNOWN_PRODUCTS
  )
  insert into INCLUDED_ENTITIES (ENTITY, BRANCH, CPTY_ENTITY, CPTY_BRANCH, PRODUCT_TYPE, PRODUCT_CATEGORY)
  select CA.ENTITY
       , CA.BRANCH
       , CA.CPTY_ENTITY
       , CA.CPTY_BRANCH
       , FINAL_PT.PRODUCT_TYPE
       , FINAL_PT.PRODUCT_CATEGORY
  from (
    select ALL_CASEID_PRODUCTS.CASEID
         , ALL_CASEID_PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_TYPE
         , ALL_CASEID_PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_CATEGORY 
    from (
           select CASEIDS.CASEID
               , KP.PRODUCT_TYPE
               , rank() over (order by CASEIDS.CASEID, KP.PRODUCT_TYPE) as ID
               , case
                   when KP.PRODUCT_TYPE = 'R1' then 'Rep'
                   when KP.PRODUCT_TYPE = 'S1' then 'Sec'
                   else 'Der'
                end as PRODUCT_CATEGORY
           from (
             select CASEID 
             from AGREEMENT_PRODUCT_EXCLUSIONS CAPE
             where date(DATA_DATE) = (select DATA_DATE from BUSINESS_DATE)
             group by CASEID
           ) CASEIDS
           cross JOIN KNOWN_PRODUCTS KP
           where date(KP.DATA_DATE) = (select DATA_DATE from BUSINESS_DATE)
           and KP.PRODUCT_TYPE != '()'
      ) ALL_CASEID_PRODUCTS
    left join AGREEMENT_PRODUCT_EXCLUSIONS E on ALL_CASEID_PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_TYPE = E.PRODUCT_TYPE
                                                 and ALL_CASEID_PRODUCTS.CASEID = E.CASEID
                                                 and date(E.DATA_DATE) = (select DATA_DATE from BUSINESS_DATE)
    where E.CASEID is null and E.PRODUCT_TYPE is null
    group by ALL_CASEID_PRODUCTS.CASEID
         , ALL_CASEID_PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_TYPE
         , ALL_CASEID_PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_CATEGORY
  ) FINAL_PT
  join AGREEMENTS CA on CA.CASEID = FINAL_PT.CASEID
                         and CA.PRODUCT_CATEGORY = FINAL_PT.PRODUCT_CATEGORY
  where date(CA.DATA_DATE) = (select DATA_DATE from BUSINESS_DATE)
  group by CA.ENTITY
        , CA.BRANCH
        , CA.CPTY_ENTITY
        , CA.CPTY_BRANCH
        , FINAL_PT.PRODUCT_TYPE
        , FINAL_PT.PRODUCT_CATEGORY;
```